# Derivative of Integral with respect to a function

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have the following function
$$
f(\tilde{x}) = \int^\tilde{x}_0 x dH(x)
$$
and I want to find $f'(\tilde{x})$. Here, $H(x)$ denotes a cumulative density function. So far, it is clear to me that I can use the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, i.e., if a function $g(x)$ is continuous and $G$ defined for a all $x \in [a,b]$ as the integral
$$
G(x) = \int^x_a g(t) dt,
$$
then $G$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and
$$
G'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} G(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int^x_a g(t) dt = (G(x)-G(a))'=G'(x)=g(x).
$$

In the problem above I do not integrate with respect to a variable but to a function. Let $F(\tilde{x})$ be the integral of $f(\tilde{x})$, then I get
$$
f'(\tilde{x}) = \frac{d}{dx} \int^\tilde{x}_0 x dH(x) = \left[f(H(\tilde{x}))-f(H(0))\right]' = 
$$

There I am somewhat stuck and not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: cumulative density function or cumulative distribution function?

Comment: I mean the cumulative distribution function, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: $f$ need not be differentiable in general.